# Clicking on a community site members will redirect to his personal page, even if it is was deleted?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, community

I have a community site, and if you click on most of the members it will redirect to the following page :-

```
 http:// vstg01:40708/discussionforum/generalDiscussion/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=20&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fgvstg01%3A40708%2Fdiscussionforum%2FgeneralDiscussion%2FSitePages%2FMembers%2Easpx
```

since these members did not create personal sites. 
While for users who have personal site, clicking on their names inside the members section will redirect to the following page:-

```
http:// vstg01/my/Person.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ew%7Cad%2Dgroup%5Ctarek%2Emeliti&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fgvstg01%3A40708%2Fdiscussionforum%2FgeneralDiscussion%2F%5Flayouts%2Fuserdisp%2Easpx%3FForce%3D1%26ID%3D13%26Source%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgvstg01%253A40708%252Fdiscussionforum%252FgeneralDiscussion%252FSitePages%252FMembers%252Easpx%26AjaxDelta%3D1%26isStartPlt1%3D1380191695010&Title=Discussion%20Forum
```

but the problem is that I have deleted all the personal sites for the members, since we do not need this. but still clicking on the members will redirect to a “Page not found “. can anyone advice on this ? baring in min d I did a iisreset after deleting the personal site collections.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

John,

Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Synchoronization -> Manage user permissions -> uncheck Create Personal Site

Here you can enable/ disable a lot of things related to MySites and User Profiles. To disable mysite creation uncheck the item that says "Create Personal Site".

**EDIT**

SEE: [Disable _layouts/userdisp.aspx redirecting to MySite/Person.aspx?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9e178a6c-fd65-4281-8097-88726f9c56e0/disable-layoutsuserdispaspx-redirecting-to-mysitepersonaspx)

Comment: If you don't want them to use My Sites.. Delete the existing ones and disable Creating My Site option!

Comment: thanks for the link,, but it seems that it did not answer the question.. and they are talking about modifying the personla page , and not preventing the redirection..

Comment: Exactly, this is default behavior now! You can edit personal page to redirect it page to _layouts/userdisp.aspx page!

Comment: how i can edit members personal pages ,, when i have deleted them !!

Comment: don't know and won't recommend that :)

Comment: so what is the best solution in my case, where i have deleted all the personal sites for the community members, but still clicking on a member username will redirect to the deleted personal site !!

Comment: so after all , i am back to where i have just started !!